# Confusion about "Return Value" concept in Sub procedure

Tags: vba, excel

I am newbie in programming concept. I know only one thing is that in VBA, a Function returns a value, but a Sub does not. I have two example of Sub procedure and both return value which is given below :

**Example1:** when i am entering value in A1 and A2 cell then it return value in A3.

```
Sub Addition()

a = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value
b = ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Value

ActiveSheet.Range("A3").Value = a + b
End Sub
```

**Example2:** it's also return me cube root value after enter any positive number:

```
Sub CubeRoot()
Num = InputBox("Enter a positive number")
MsgBox Num ^ (1/3) & "is the cube root."
End Sub
```

Then how both (Function and Sub) are different to each other. Please correct me ?

Comment: For one, neither is "returning" anything.  The first writes to output (the `ActiveSheet`) and the second displays a user interface.

Comment: Subs never return anything, only functions do that : http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/volatile-functions.html
You can

Comment: @Comintern, When i entered value in cell A1 = 3 and cell A2 = 2 then it return value 5 in cell A3. and In Example2, when i enter any value in inputbox then it return value (cuberoot)

Comment: No, it ***writes*** the value to the cell.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1070/user-defined-functions-udfs#t=201701201356112407535&a=syntax

Comment: To make it more clear what others have said: a sub _can_ return something, but only as a side-effect of it's workings, not in the strict programming sense that functions return something.

Comment: @comintern, is there any difference in "Return" and "Writes". Please explain with simple example .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that a `Function` returns a value but a `Sub` does not.  That difference means that a `Function` can be used as if it were a value, but a `Sub` cannot.  For example,

```
Function twelve() as Long
    twelve = 12
End Function
```

permits you to say

```
Debug.Print 3 + twelve
```

in just the same way you can say

```
Debug.Print 3 + 12
```

The "return value" of the function is the value that will participate in whatever expression you include the function in.  In VBA, that return value has the same name as the function (e.g., `twelve` above).

In a `Sub`, whatever the `Sub` may do, and whatever values it may produce, it cannot be used as if it were a value.  For example, your `CubeRoot` sub cannot be used in an expression like

```
Debug.Print 2 * CubeRoot()      ' Doesn't compile
```

However, a function can:

```
Function CubeRootFunction(d as Double) as Double
    CubeRootFunction = d ^ (1.0/3.0)
End Function

Debug.Print 2 * CubeRootFunction(8)    ' Compiles and works fine
```

Hope that helps!  Do check out the links the commenters posted for more examples.